# How to define the delay time based on the source?

Tags: delay, anylogic

i'm new using AnyLogic and i don't have many knowledge of programmation, i think that is important to make that clear. I did another question early but i think that i dont explain it very well. So, now i wanna try to do that:

Ok, i need to do a model about an access control, and here is the thing: my process has two delays 1. revision of the car/bus/trailer. 2. registration, but, the time of delay in the revision process is different depending on the type of the car, e.g. to revise the car the security guard expend 2 minutes, and to revise the trailer expend 10 minutes. I want to make it clear that difference in the delay block, because i want to my model look like this: [AnyLogic Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcufv.png)

The problem is that i don't know how to do that, i tried to do different things that i read on this foro but i had many problems. If everyone here can help me to do that in a easy way i'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how you differentiate your agents. Assume there is a boolean parameter `isCar` in your agent type:

Then, in the delay block's "delay time" code, you can simply write `agent.isCar ? 2 : 10`

If you have different agent types `Car` and `Trailer` flowing through the delay block, you would need to write `agent instanceof Car ? 2 : 10`

But you need to understand a lot more of the basics. Do the tutorials, study MANY of the example models to get a feel for how to do things. Learn OOP, Java and read [this](https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling) article to understand what `agent` means above.